# Update an element in an array which is within an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Schema

```
{
    _id: 'Unique_id',
    array_key: [{
            'm1': [7, 5, 6, 6, 1, 2, 3]
        },
        {
            'm2': [1, 5, 3, 7, 9, 2, 3]
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to update any element in `array_key`s m1 field's array.

```
{'m1': [7,5,6,6,1,2,3]}
```

E.g. I want to update 6 at index 3 in that array. 
I found this in MongoDB's [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)

It seems that one is allowed to add value at specific position but not update it (going by that documentation).

~p.s Later I'd try to implement this using mongoose

Update : The array_key in the schema will hold daily work hour for an employee which will be represented in months format on the frontend. m1 and m2 are used in that respect.

Comment: If you are always going to know the "key" and the "position" then just use it `{ "$set": { "m1.2": 10 } }` would set position 2 ( n-1 == 3 - 1 == 2 ) to 10. Presuming that each element was individually named "m1", "m2", "m3", etc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: okay tried this `db.collectionname.update({ID MATCHING},{$set : {"array_key.$.m1.2" : 2} })`. It did work for array that are not nested.

Comment: I was actually talking specifically about doing that **without** a [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)
 since we already know you cannot do that with nested arrays. I was actually pointing out that as long as the **m** element was always **unique** then you just notate according to what dimensions you want. And yes I actually did mean `{ "$set": { "array_key.m1.2": 10  } }`

Comment: "since we already know you cannot do that with nested arrays" - I wasn't actually 100 percent sure, I thought there might be a way which I don't know.

Comment: "I was actually pointing out that as long as the m element was always unique then you just notate according to what dimensions you want."  - I didn't get it?

Comment: "And yes I actually did mean { "$set": { "array_key.m1.2": 10 } }" - It didn't work either.

Comment: Why can't you just answer a simple question? Your key names `"m1", "m2"` Are they "unique"? If so then what are they doing inside an array in the first place?

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes they are. The array key (mentioned above) there will hold daily averages for all 12 months. So there at one place in the schema, I understand that other option is to have individual 12 key value pairs for them, I haven't decided on that yet. What are the disadvantages btw with this approach. I know that nested objects hamper Mongo's performance but these array of objects aren't that huge.

Comment: Try and explain your use case better in your question. But for the sort of "updates" you are describing you are better off with `array_key : {'m1':[7,5,6,6,1,2,3], 'm2':[1,5,3,7,9,2,3] }` and update notation which I already mentioned

Comment: Simple JSON object sounds fine. Updated the question.

Comment: Key value pair as mentioned by @NeilLunn is the way to go which provides direct updates, but just wanted to give you solution for nested arrays structure. You can directly reach the nested array by chaining index like  `db.collection.update({ID_MATCHING}, {"$set": { "array_key.0.m1.2": 2 } })` or 
  You can write something like `db.collection.update({ID_MATCHING, "array_key.m1":{ $exists: true}},{"$set": { "array_key.$.m1.2": 2 } })`. This will make use of positional operator to locate top level `m1` array value followed by index of the nested array element to update.
`

Comment: @Veeram Actually the whole point was deliberately trying to remove use of `$exists` from the start, and pointing out that if you are going to put a "unique key" inside an array, then you do not really want an array in the first place.